# Looping in liquid and doing something every x loops

Tags: liquid

I am working with liquid templating, I am wanting to loop through an array, and spit out some HTML that looks like this,

```
    <div class="classname">
        <div>
          <a>1</a>
          <a>2</a>
          <a>3</a>
          <a>4</a>
          <a>5</a>
          <a>6</a>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="classname">
        <div>
          <a>7</a>
          <a>8</a>
          <a>9</a>
          <a>10</a>
          <a>11/a>
          <a>12</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="classname">
        <div>
          <a>13</a>
          <a>14</a>
          <a>15</a>
          <a>16</a>
          <a>17/a>
          <a>18</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So basically for every 6 loops I want open 2 new divs and close the previous 2. I have had a go this is my effort.

```
{% for block in content_blocks %}
            {% assign mod = forloop.index | modulo: 6 %}
              {% if mod / 6 == 1 %}
                <div class="grid-slide">
                    <div>
            {% endif %}
                        <a href="{{block.content_block_url}}" class="location-link">
                            <img src="{{block.content_block_image | url_for_generic_image}}" />
                        </a>
            {% if mod / 6 == 1 %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with this liquid code:

```
{% assign content_blocks_length = content_blocks | size %}
{% for block in content_blocks %}
    {% assign mod = forloop.index | modulo: 6 %}
    {% if mod  == 1 and  forloop.index != 1 %}
        </div>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
      {% if mod  == 1 %}
        <div class="grid-slide">
            <div>
    {% endif %}
        <a href="{{block.content_block_url}}" class="location-link">
            <img src="{{block.content_block_image | url_for_generic_image}}" />
        </a>
    {% if forloop.index == content_blocks_length %}
        </div>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

To start a loop from where the last loop using the same iterator left off, pass the special word ***continue***.

```
<!-- if array = [1,2,3,4,5,6] -->
{% for item in array limit: 3 %}
  {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
{% for item in array limit: 3 offset: continue %}
  {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

This is a textbook example of how this can be done, but it's uncomfortable that you have to repeat the code after each limit. You can find more about this on: https://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/iteration/

So I deleted my version and used [Victor's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1954204/victor-leontyev), you just need to write it one time. Beautiful....